# prototype of int64_t or offset64 both linux and windows 32bits system

Tags: windows, linux, int64

I am developing a application which needs functions of int64 variables. and i was told offset64 or int64_t is viable for my need...
But i just wanna what is the prototype of int64 under 32bit system...
How can i use the variable.
is it a struction which consists of two ULONGs?
thanx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's usually no reason why the compiler can't support 64-bit integer types
transparently on a 32-bit (or smaller) platform since it can generate the code
necessary to handle them in smaller chunks whenever they are used. AFAIK
any C99-compliant compiler should support 64-bit types transparently
through the stdint.h header file which defines types such as int64_t and
you can use them as you would any other integer type.

[Edit] Example :

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
        int64_t x = 0x1000000000LL;

        x = x*2;
        printf("%llX\n", x);
}
```

Comment: do u have some examples of using int64. thanx

Comment: You should use "int64_t", not "int64". int64_t is the standard-defined
type.

Answer (score 1):

Use long long, both msvc and gcc support it.